# Not getting correct last password changed date for cms member?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

I am using uCommerce with the cms member. For the forgot password password link validation i want the last password changed date for the required member but it gives wrong date as current date time value.

```
String userName = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(email);
MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(userName);
if (membershipUser.LastPasswordChangedDate > date)
{

----- validation Where date is the datetime when user request forgot password request and link will sent to him

---- but all the time LastPasswordChangedDategetting current date time, so can not able to set the validation

}
```

Any Idea?

Thanks

Girish

Comment: What's the structure of `LastPasswordChangedDate` and `date`? Are they `DateTime` objects?

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the following and it seems to be working for me. Could you try the following:

```
string userName = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(email);
MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(userName);

if (membershipUser != null && membershipUser.LastPasswordChangedDate.Date > DateTime.Now.Date)
{
    // Do something
}
```